# How to organize a list of todos by category using arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How to print the array elements by category using Ruby?

Here I have `todos` an array of arrays:

```
todos = [
      ["Send invoice", "money"],
      ["Clean room", "organize"],
      ["Pay rent", "money"],
      ["Arrange books", "organize"],
      ["Pay taxes", "money"],
      ["Buy groceries", "food"]
    ]
```

I want to build an array just for categories which looks like this:

```
[["money", ["Send invoice", "Pay rent", "Pay taxes"]], ...]
```

**Expected output:**

```
  money:
     Send invoice
     Pay rent
     Pay taxes
   organize:
     Clean room
     Arrange books
   food:
     Buy groceries
```

**Here is my attempt:**

```
    a, b, c = ["money"], ["organize"], ["food"]

for i in todos  
    if i[1]  ==  "money"
            arr = []
        a.push(arr.push(i[0]))  #=> ["money", ["Send invoice"], ["Pay rent"], ["Pay taxes"]]
    elsif i[1] == "organize"
            arr = []
        b.push(arr.push(i[0]))  #=> ["organize", ["Clean room"], ["Arrange books"]]
    else
            arr = []
        c.push(arr.push(i[0])). #=> ["food", ["Buy groceries"]]
    end 
end
```

---

**Explanation:**
Here in my code I have directly assigned values to the array `a, b, c = ["money"], ["organize"], ["food"]` which is wrong.
How do I get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
todos = [
  ["Send invoice", "money"],
  ["Clean room", "organize"],
  ["Pay rent", "money"],
  ["Arrange books", "organize"],
  ["Pay taxes", "money"],
  ["Buy groceries", "food"]
]

todos.group_by(&:last).map { |key, values| [key, values.map(&:first)] }
#=> [["money", ["Send invoice", "Pay rent", "Pay taxes"]], ["organize", ["Clean room", "Arrange books"]], ["food", ["Buy groceries"]]]
```

How does this work? [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:group_by) returns the nested array grouped by their [`Array#last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html) value and will return a nested hash structure like this:

```
{
  "money"=>[["Send invoice", "money"], ["Pay rent", "money"], ["Pay taxes", "money"]],
  "organize"=>[["Clean room", "organize"], ["Arrange books", "organize"]],
  "food"=>[["Buy groceries", "food"]]
}
```

In the next step of the method chain, it uses [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to translate each key/value pair to the final structure by returning an array with the key from the `grouped_by` and a nested array containing only the [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-first) values from the original values. For example, it will take this input in one of the iterations and translate it to:

```
{ "organize"=>[["Clean room", "organize"], ["Arrange books", "organize"]] }
# with `key` being "organize", and `values` being the nested arrays on the right
# getting translated into:
#=> ["organize", ["Clean room", "Arrange books"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `#each_with_object` to iterate over `todos`, building a hash, which seems a much more useful data structure for this task.

```
h = todos.each_with_object({}) do |arr, h|
  task, category = arr 
  h[category] ||= []
  h[category] << task 
end
# => {"money"=>["Send invoice", "Pay rent", "Pay taxes"], 
#     "organize"=>["Clean room", "Arrange books"], 
#     "food"=>["Buy groceries"]}
```

Doing this is equivalent to:

```
h = {}

for arr in todos
  task = arr.first
  category = arr.last

  h[category] = [] unless h.has_key? category
  h[category].push(task)
end
```

To turn this into the array of arrays...

```
h.map { |k, v| [k, v] }
# => [["money", ["Send invoice", "Pay rent", "Pay taxes"]], 
#     ["organize", ["Clean room", "Arrange books"]], 
#     ["food", ["Buy groceries"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
todos = [
  ["Send invoice", "money"],
  ["Clean room", "organize"],
  ["Pay rent", "money"],
  ["Arrange books", "organize"],
  ["Pay taxes", "money"],
  ["Buy groceries", "food"]
]

todos.group_by(&:last).transform_values{ |v| v.map(:first) }
```

here we are using `group_by` method with shorthand method calling
and this returns a hash where the keys are the evaluated result from the block and the values are arrays of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.

also we are using `transform_values` method with block and this transform hash values according to given block

result of above statement

```
=> {"money"=>["Send invoice", "Pay rent", "Pay taxes"], "organize"=>["Clean room", "Arrange books"], "food"=>["Buy groceries"]}
```

Comment: can you pls do this without using any direct methods. and my question is to get output only using the array. no hash allowed. thank you mr. @Ritesh

Comment: nearly i have voted more than 100 reputations for you @Ritesh bro.
but why are you not voting for me and even not answering the request i have commented on your post. this is not fair